# Firebase password validation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I have a forum I'm trying to create using firebase. Certain subforums can only be accessed if the user knows the password. At the time of joining, the client retrieves the password of the subforum and then checks if the entered password is correct.

Is there a way to do the password validation server side instead?

Comment: are you doing validation server side or client side ?

Comment: I'm currently retrieving the password to the client and then checking the input against this password whenever the user hits submit. I'd rather send the password to firebase and get a boolean response.

Comment: i assume you know how to fetch user data from firebase. So what else do you need? Compare input values with fetched user data. isn't it what you want or am i missing something?

Comment: I want the comparison and validation to happen server side instead of client side.

Comment: post your code so more people understand what is actually you want ...........

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use a different aproach to tackle this problem. Instead of giving out passwords i suggest you keep a list of the users that can access the subforum in firebase (only admin should be able to write to this list) and use the firebase security rules to check if someone can read / write to the subforum based on that list.

The rules for your subforum would look a bit like this then:

```
"forums":{
      "$subforum_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('subforums').child($subforum_id).hasChild(auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('subforums').child($subforum_id).hasChild(auth.uid)"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scenarios is quite whacky. You want to do away with user names and only have passwords. How are you planning to know who modified the forum entry if you don't identify them?

Anyways, for your ask, you can work something like below where you impersonate a pre-created user when an anonymous user wants to access a forum -

1. Enable email authentication in firebase.
2. For every forum password, create a user with these values -

   ```
   username: forumName@yoursite.com
   password: forumpassword
   ```

   Note its uid.
3. Add the respective uid as a child "uid" property to the corresponding forum.
4. Add simple security rules for password protected forums -

   ```
   "forums":{
     "$subforum_id": {
       ".read": "auth.uid == data.child('uid')",
       ".write": "auth.uid == data.child('uid')"
     }
   }
   ```
5. Now when an anonymous user wants to access a forum, she must give a password and you will need to hardcode the user name with the appropriate one for the forum she is trying to access. This way you impersonate an anonymous user as the forum user provided she knows the password.

Comment: So it's a forum where users can voice concerns anonymously. Passwords would be given out in real life and users would register with their google account and have displaynames that they can choose. Forums have a high rate of joining and leaving which is why I don't want to keep a list of allowed users that would require a moderator to update.

Comment: The suggestion is not to enforce users, but as you want to use firebase server side authentication, you would need to impersonate a valid user, hence the need to create one user per private forum.

Comment: Can multiple users be authenticated with both their google id and a be authenticated with the fake forum account?

Comment: So you do have authentication? It'd help if you explain in more detail how your users access the site.